# Struct Student Record Program

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble trying to print from the input file and my output doesn't print anything. I've tried looping to print the whole file but I am trying to read the first name and it still coming out as an error. (code isn't complete regarding average and grade info) I've been struggling with this project and it's the first time I work with structs. This is a menu program that has many options and I can't finish up my project since I'm having horrible time trying to figure out how to actually read the list. In need of some major help! thanks

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#define CAP 30
using namespace std ;

struct Student{
    string Course_Name,Course_Id, Course_Location;
    string  FirstName, LastName;
    float   Quiz, Test[6] ;
    int Id;

} ;

bool Open_File(ifstream &fin);
void Read_Student(Student Temp, ifstream & fin);
int Read_list(Student List[], int Max_Size);
void Print_List(Student List[], int Size);

int main()
{
    Student Temp;
    Student stu[CAP];
    int     Logical_Size = 0 ;
    Logical_Size = Read_list(stu,CAP);
    if (Logical_Size > 0 ){
        Print_List(stu,Logical_Size);
    }
    else
        cout << "Empty file\n\n";
    return 0 ;


}
void Read_Student(Student Temp , ifstream & fin){

    fin >>Temp.FirstName >> Temp.LastName;
    fin >> Temp.Id;
    fin >> Temp.Quiz;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
        fin >> Temp.Test[6];
    fin.ignore(10,'\n');
}

int Read_list(Student List[], int Max_Size)
{

    Student Temp;
    ifstream fin;
    int     i = 0;

    if (Open_File(fin))
    {

        getline(fin, List[i].Course_Name);
        getline(fin, List[i].Course_Id);
        getline(fin, List[i].Course_Location);
        Read_Student(List[i],fin);
        while(!fin.eof())
        {
            i++ ;
            if (i == Max_Size){
                cout << "\nArray is full.\n" ;
                break;
            }
        }
        Read_Student(List[i],fin);
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"\nBad file. Did not open. Program terminated.\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return (i);
}


void Print_List(Student List[], int Size){
    Student Temp;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Course Name: " << List[i].Course_Name << endl;
    cout << "Course ID:  " << List[i].Course_Id << endl;
    cout << "Course Location: " << List[i].Course_Location << endl;

    cout <<left << fixed << setprecision(2) <<showpoint <<endl <<endl ;
    cout << setw(20) << "\nName" << setw(20) << "ID" << setw(25) << "Average" << setw(20)
    << "Grade" << endl;
    cout << "===========================================================================" << endl;


        cout << setw(19) << List[i].LastName +", "+ List[i].FirstName << setw(20) << List[i].Id << setw(20) ;



}
bool Open_File(ifstream &fin)
{
    string    File_Name;
    cout <<"Enter file name: ";
    getline(cin, File_Name);
    fin.open(File_Name.c_str());
    if(fin.fail())
        return false ;
    else
        return true ;
}
```

Sample input file :

```
Intro To Computer C++
SAL 343
JHG 344
John Adams
111223333 100 87 93 90 90 89 91 
Willy Smith Jr.
222114444 90 73 67 77 70 80 90 
Phil Jordan
777886666 100 80 70 -50 60 90 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems, I'll start with one and work my way down. Here...

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    fin >> Temp.Test[6];
```

...you are always operating on the seventh element (zero-based) of the array, however that's no good, you know that b/c you've used the fact as the `for` control. What you need is `Temp.Test[i]`. That's not all though, because you didn't pass `Temp` as a reference, so you do all that hard work for nothing, as the changes don't persist. What you need is `void Read_Student(Student &Temp , ifstream &fin)`.

Unless I'm missing something this...

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    i++ ;
    if (i == Max_Size){
        cout << "\nArray is full.\n" ;
        break;
    }
}
Read_Student(List[i],fin);
```

...doesn't seem to be doing what you want it to. It basically increments `i` until it reaches the `MAX_SIZE`, breaks and then attempts to read an element that is outside of your bounds. I'm sure you intended, based on your sample file, to read the rest of the students until the `eof` is reached, but as you can see you really only read one additional one. You probably meant that to be *inside* the `while`.

In terms of reading those students, I agree with another answer which suggests removing your `ignore()`. There's probably a better way of dealing with it like just reading a line and parse it out, *IMHO* of course.

You'd also be well served to make a `Course` class. The way you've designed your `struct`, each student has all the course info but you only extract it once as it is only in the file once.

I know you asked about printing problems, I just can't see anyway to deal with that until these issues are addressed.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your time. You made everything so clear and everything worked perfectly! I really appreciate your help. I understand everything now and fixed most of my problems. It all worked when I removed the "Jr" from Willy Smith Jr. but with it included in the file it causes errors like the past user said. How can I read the last name for example as Smith Jr. being the last name instead of having middle initial?

Comment: @user2914173: No problem. There are a many options. You could just read that entire line and pull out the pieces and handle the situation when it arises. Or read the first name as you do then add another statement that crabs the rest of the line and sets that as the last name. Or if you have control over how the data is written you could do it then and not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of code to see if it's fixed,

```
fin.ignore(10,'\n');
```

And, there is one problem with the input you provided. There is a redundant string in this line,

```
Willy Smith Jr.
```

That will cause error in subsequent `cin` readings.

Comment: removing fin.ignore doesn't fix my problem. I'm starting to think I am reading the file wrong or something or I am printing incorrectly. The problem is I've tried everything logically but I'm having this issue that is stopping me from doing everything else